# Wireless Connection for Vortex and MicroFreak

Tags: midi, synthesizer, midi-controller-keyboard, keytar

I'm looking for a simple way to connect a keytar (Alesis Vortex) to a synth (Arturia MicroFreak) through wireless midi.

[image: Vortex and MicroFreak boards]

My first hope is that since the Vortex comes with a USB-A dongle I can use a USB-AF to USB-BM adapter to plug directly into the MicroFreak.
[image: Alesis Vortex Wireless Dongle]
This is the adapter shown below.
[image: USB-A Female to USB-B Male Adapter]
I don't know whether or not this would actually work because I'm not sure whether the MicroFreak will recognize information from the Dongle or not. It seems that some midi, especially wireless so far as I can tell, requires some sort of driver/setup to be installed on the receiving device. Should the synth already function with it?

If not, are there other wireless options buying a set of transmitters that would work with these two?

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to take a swing at this without concrete evidence, just 'prior knowledge'.

I doubt it.
I don't know any of those devices, but apart from your 'frankenstein' adaptor [which I can't really fathom the purpose of], all your USB ports/plugs are client-side devices.
USB-A requires a client at one end & a host at the other. The way the plug spec is designed, if a client plugs straight into a host it has the 'flat' plug; if it needs a connecting cable, the cable has the 'flat' plug at the host end & a 'house' shape at the client end. This is so you just can't connect things up the wrong way.

USB-C, now *is* capable of this duality, which is why the plugs are the same at both ends. The connectivity of client/host is negotiated by the hardware as it's connected. USB-A cannot do that.

So, even your dongle needs to be connected to a host - a computer in other words. There's potential this will then work using the computer itself to enable the midi transmission - but for that I'd need to know more about each system. Presumably the Vortex is designed to be able to use that dongle to wirelessly connect to a computer - which then needs to be configured to pass wired MIDI through to your Arturia.